# Java: Call JInternalFrame fron another JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I am developing a desktop Application in Java Swing. 
I am facing a problem showing a JInternalFrame from Another JInternal Frame.

I have 3 Frames
The main frame, in Which i put jdesktopPane is  (frmMain)
and 2 JInternalFrames (f1 and f2)

I have menus in frmMain from where i can call and display the 2 JInternalFrames easily
but the problem is 
How to call f1 from clicking a button on f2.

Comment: for all your posts, everywhere ---> for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.m. issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create f1 frame object on f2 button action

```
F1 f1 = new F1();
```

Then create a JDesktopPane object like this

```
JDesktopPane desktopPane = getDesktopPane();
desktopPane.add(f1);//add f1 to desktop pane
f1.setVisible(true);// set the f1 frame visible
```

Finally if needed dispose the current frame

```
this.dispose();
```

Comment: you rocks, Thanks for the solution